# ::func has not been declared error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

What I'm trying to do is essentially be able to call a function and have it register a c++ function with lua. Basically something like registerFunction(function). Now, I know that there are libraries that do this for you, however I want to learn how somebody would write a library like that.

My current method is to use templates to generate the relevant glue function for the function that is passed to it.

My code right now looks like this:

```
template<typename F>
struct registerStruct
{
    template<typename T>
    struct inner
    {
        static int func(lua_State*);
    };
};
template<typename F>
void registerFunction(const char *name,F function)
{
    lua_register(this->L,name,&registerStruct<decltype(function)>::inner<function>::func);
}

template<typename F>
struct registerStruct<F(void)> //I would write more classes for different numbers of arguments
{
    template<F(*T)(void)>
    struct inner
    {
        static int func(lua_State *L)
        {
            returnLua(L,T()); //push the return value onto lua's stack
            return 1;
        }
    };
};
```

Then I try to use it like this:

```
int test(void)
{
    std::cout<<"hello from c++"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

registerFunction("test",test);
```

Compiling with gcc yields the error ::func has not been declared.

Comment: Why are you using `this->` in a non-member function?

Answer (score 1):

```
registerStruct<decltype(function)>::inner<function>::func
```

For one thing, `decltype(function)` could be replaced with `F`.

Also, the class template `inner` expects a type as its template argument, and `function` is an expression, not a type.  That should probably be `::inner<F>`.

(Or maybe `inner` doesn't need to be a template at all.  A nested class `outer<T>::inner` can still use template parameter `T` attached to its enclosing class.)

The C++ syntax requires a few weird things to help parsers figure out what templates mean.  Normally the meaning of C++ depends on whether an identifier is for a variable (object or reference), a type, or a template.  But after a `::` or `.` or `->` in a template, if the type of the operator's left side depends on a template parameter, it would be impossible to figure out during initial parsing which the next name is.  If you don't help it out, the language will assume the name is a variable.

So C++ thinks `registerStruct<decltype(function)>::inner` is a variable.  Then we have the less-than operator `<`, followed by the valid expression `function`, then the greater-than operator `>`, and then `::func`.  Wait, there's nothing called `::func`!

To specify `inner` is really a template, you need

```
&registerStruct<F>::template inner<F>::func
```

Comment: >decltype(function) could be replaced with F. But F is int(\*)(void), while all my templates are written in terms of function signatures. Surely they must be different as std::function<int(\*)(void)> won't compile while std::function<decltype(test)> will. >Also, the class template inner expects a type as its template argument, and function is an expression But I need T to be a pointer to a function, otherwise it won't work. How can template<int(\*T)(void)> void function(void){T()} take a pointer to a function, but my template can't?

Comment: Since you put `template<typename T> struct inner`, the template argument for `inner` must always be a type.  `template<int(*T)(void)>` specifies a non-type template parameter; that is, a certain value of the exactly specified type.